# React TypeScript Jest Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to run uni test on react with typescript.

Here are the npm packages I am using:

```
"@types/enzyme": "^3.10.4",
"@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
"@types/jest": "^25.0.0",
"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.3",
"jest": "^25.0.0",
"jest-cli": "^25.0.0",
"ts-jest": "^24.3.0"
```

est.config.ts

```
module.exports = {

  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      diagnostics: {
        warnOnly: true
      }
    }
  },

  // Setup Enzyme
  snapshotSerializers: ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv:
  [
     "<rootDir>/src/setupEnzyme.ts"
  ] 
};
```

setupEnzyme.ts

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });
```

the test function

```
export const sum = (...a: number[]) => a.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
```

the tests

```
import { sum } from './foo';

/**
 * Basic Example
 */
test('basic', () => {
  expect(sum()).toBe(0);
});

test('basic again', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});

/**
 * Async Example
 *
 * Jest has built-in async/await support. e.g.
 */
test('basic async', async () => {
  expect(sum()).toBe(0);
});

test('basic async again', async () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

foo.ts and foo.test.ts are located in **tests** folder.

the error is:

FAIL  src/**tests**/foo.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Your test suite must contain at least one test.

  at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:163:18)
```

PASS  src/**tests**/foo.test.ts

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.714s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wasyster.git.com@0.0.1 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the wasyster.git.com@0.0.1 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wasyster\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-01-15T16_23_16_125Z-debug.log

in my folder structure there are a *.babelrc* file with the following content

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["emotion", "transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

I can provide any configuration file if needed more.

thnx

Comment: Your test runner is picking up your source code as a test file, move it outside your `test` folder